# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production even it's already change to false

Tags: django, vps

I host in Niagahoster using VPS

```
My directory is like this
    root
    |- cyberpanel
    |———cyberpanel
    |—————-settings.py
    |- manage.py
```

I already change debug status to false which is located only in that folder. I tried to list all files. I already waited around 2 hours but still no change.

[This is the warning, it still gave me a security warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw8hs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment that line in your `settings.py`.
I think you uncommented that line by accident.